# How to update component based on container's state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React container called `UserContainer` which renders a component called `UserComponent`.

The code looks approximately like this (I have removed the unnecessary bits):

```
 // **** CONTAINER **** //
    class UserContainer extends React.Component<ContainerProps, ContainerState> {
    state = { firstName: "placeholder" };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await this.props.callUserApi();

        if (response.ok) {
            const content: ContainerState = await response.json();
            this.setState({ firstName: content.firstName });
        }
    }

    private isChanged(componentState: ComponentState) {
        return this.state.firstName === componentState.firstName;
    }

    async save(newValues: ComponentState) {
        if (!this.isChanged(newValues)) {
            console.log("No changes detected.");
            return;
        }

        const response = await this.props.changeFirstName(newValues.firstName);

        if (response.ok) {
            const content: ContainerState = await response.json();
            this.setState({ firstName: content.firstName });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <UserComponent firstName={this.state.firstName} onSave={(newValues: ComponentState) => this.save(newValues)} />;
    }
}

export default UserContainer;

// **** COMPONENT **** //

class UserComponent extends React.PureComponent<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
    constructor(props: ComponentProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {  firstName: props.firstName }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={evt => this.setState({ firstName: evt.target.value})} />
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.onSave(this.state)}>Save</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserComponent;
```

The problem is that `this.state.firstName` in the component is always "placeholder". Even after the container gets its values from the API, the `state` of the component is not changed (however, the `props` are changed). When adding `console.log` into the individual methods, the flow of individual steps is following:

1. Container render()
2. Component constructor()
3. Component render()
4. Container didMount()
5. Container render()
6. Component render()

As you can see, the component constructor is called just once, prior to the container receiving its data from the backend API. Is there a way to pass the updated container state into the component in order to display the real data?

Answer (score 1):

There are really FEW cases where updating state by props is necessary, I suggest you to read the full blog post from facebook under paragraph "Preferred Solutions": https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing the updated data to the component. Only mistake is, you are assigning it once. So, whenever you get the updated values, it doesn't reflect, since you don't have only assigned it once.

Two ways to go about it.

1. If there is no manipulation taking place. Change `this.state.firstName` to `this.props.firstName`

   ```
           <input type="text" value={this.props.firstName} onChange={evt => this.setState({ firstName: evt.target.value})} />
   ```
2. If there is some manipulation taking place, you'll be doing it in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method and then setting your `firstName` state. This method will be triggered whenever you'll be updating the states.
   Example -

   ```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if(this.props.firstName!==nextProps.firstName) {
           //do your validation
       }
    }
   ```

**EDIT**

As dubes rightly pointed out, `componentWillReceiveProps` method is deprecated. So you'll have to use the `static getDerivedStateFromProps` and have to return the new resulting state from this method.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: cwrp lifecycle is marked for removal in future. Please take a look at `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Comment: According to https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is reserved only for rare use cases. Is my use case really that rare? Or should I rather use one of the suggested alternatives?

Comment: yes it's indeed for rare use cases. as far as i guess. you shouldn't need to use this method. only doing it by `this.props.firstName` should solve your purpose of displaying the updated values

Comment: But when I change the value to `this.props.firstName` then the input cannot be manipulated. I would have to change the state of the container every time I change the input value, which seems like a bad practice to me. Moreover, I would lose the ability to check whether the input was changed or not (the `isChanged` method in the container).

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserComponent extends React.PureComponent<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
    constructor(props: ComponentProps) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {  firstName: props.firstName }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: ComponentProps){
        if(nextProps.firstName != this.props.firstName){
            this.state = {  firstName: nextProps.firstName }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={evt => this.setState({ firstName: evt.target.value})} />
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.onSave(this.state)}>Save</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

For latest React version please use **getDerivedStateFromProps**